# Can hidden service owners sell their domain?

Tags: onion-services

I'm still learning about hidden services and I was wondering if hidden service domains could be on sale. I've seen websites on the clearnet such as http://thisdomainisforsale.com/, that are selling their domain. So can hidden service owners sell their domain too? If so, would the payment be in cryptocurrency such as Bitcoin or Monero? And has this ever been done before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically yes.

However selling an onion service domain means selling the private key, as such the seller has to know the private key. Having the private key means you can be the onion service and decrypt any messages encrypted with the public key, and so any buyer would have to trust the seller to not keep the private key and impersonate or otherwise use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a good idea indeed. If you have got high-end PC then you can generate vanity v3 domains with 9-10 characters as per the requirements of your client through any vanity domain generation tool like mkp224o. As it takes a very much time to generate such domains you can generate public keys and private keys for your clients and can make easy money through it!